# Adding a backtracking algorithm for max coin collecting?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, backtracking, max-path

i have this psudocode for the backtracking to find the path backward from the cell(6,6).

> If F[i − 1, j] > F[i, j − 1]  then the path to (i, j) came from above.
>   If F[i − 1, j] < F[i, j − 1]  then the path to (i, j) came from the
>   left. If F[i − 1, j] = F[i, j − 1] then either direction works"

im not sure how to modify my code to do this, but i'm sure it goes somewhere between the ** ** code, i want it to print out the indices of the path the code traverses, for example for the out put given it should print something like  (6,6)(5,6)(4,6)(4,5)(4,4)(3,4)(3,3)(2,3)(1,3)(1,2)(1,1)

```
import java.util.Random;
public class project {
private static int max(int i, int j) {
    return i > j ? i : j;
}
public static int collect(int[][] board) {

    int rowLen = board.length;
    int columnLen = board[0].length;
    int[][] F = new int[rowLen][columnLen];
    F[0][0] = (int) board[0][0];


    for (int column = 1; column < columnLen; column++) {
        F[0][column] = (int)(F[0][column - 1] + board[0][column]);
    }

    **for (int row = 1; row < rowLen; row++) {
        F[row][0] = (int)(F[row - 1][0] + board[row][0]);
        for (int column = 1; column < columnLen; column++) {
            F[row][column] = (int)(max(F[row - 1][column],
                F[row][column - 1]) + board[row][column]);**
        }  
    }   

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("maxpath board");
    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 6; column++) {
            System.out.print(F[row][column] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    return F[rowLen - 1][columnLen - 1];
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create the grid
    final int rowWidth = 6;
    final int colHeight = 6;
    final int[] coinvalues = {
        0,
        1
    };
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] board = new int[rowWidth][colHeight];
    for (int[] board1: board) {
        for (int col = 0; col < board1.length; col++) {
            board1[col] = coinvalues[rand.nextInt(coinvalues.length)];
        }
    }System.out.println("coinboard");
    //display output
    for (int[] board1: board) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board1.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(board1[j] + " ");
            //System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum Coins : " + collect(board));

}
}
sample output- coinboard
1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 1 1 1 0 1 
-------------------------------------------
maxpath board
1  1  2  3  4  4  
1  1  3  3  4  4  
1  1  4  4  5  5  
2  2  5  5  6  7  
2  3  5  6  6  8  
3  4  6  7  7  9


Maximum Coins : 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my edit on your question to do the task( Btw my code always gives priority to moving up than moving left in backtracking when both give same profit) -

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Random;
class project {
private static int max(int i, int j) {
    return i > j ? i : j;
}
public static void paste(int i,int j){
    System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")");
}
public static int collect(int[][] board) {

    int rowLen = board.length;
    int columnLen = board[0].length;
    int[][] F = new int[rowLen][columnLen];
    F[0][0] = (int) board[0][0];


    for (int column = 1; column < columnLen; column++) {
        F[0][column] = (int)(F[0][column - 1] + board[0][column]);
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < rowLen; row++) {
        F[row][0] = (int)(F[row - 1][0] + board[row][0]);
        for (int column = 1; column < columnLen; column++) {
            F[row][column] = (int)(max(F[row - 1][column],
                F[row][column - 1]) + board[row][column]);
        }  
    }   

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("maxpath board");
    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 6; column++) {
            System.out.print(F[row][column] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();

}
int curr=F[rowLen - 1][columnLen - 1];
int i=rowLen-1;
int j=columnLen-1;
paste(i+1,j+1);
while(i>0&&j>0){

    if(i>0&&F[i-1][j]==curr){
        i=i-1;
    }
    else if(j>0&&F[i][j-1]==curr){
        j=j-1;
    }
    else if(i>0&&F[i-1][j]==curr-1){    
        i=i-1;
        curr--;
        paste(i+1,j+1);
    }
    else if(j>0&&F[i][j-1]==curr-1){    
        j=j-1;
        curr--;
        paste(i+1,j+1);
    }

}
    return F[rowLen - 1][columnLen - 1];
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create the grid
    final int rowWidth = 6;
    final int colHeight = 6;
    final int[] coinvalues = {
        0,
        1
    };
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] board = new int[rowWidth][colHeight];
    for (int[] board1: board) {
        for (int col = 0; col < board1.length; col++) {
            board1[col] = coinvalues[rand.nextInt(coinvalues.length)];
        }
    }System.out.println("coinboard");
    //display output
    for (int[] board1: board) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board1.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(board1[j] + " ");
            //System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum Coins : " + collect(board));

}
}
```

Comment: It runs and returns a path out , i have to mod it so it always ends at 1,1 instead of just somewhere at the 1st column or 1st row, and it seems to be skipping steps though every set of indices it gives are correct. thank you so much! i was just stuck trying to figure out the logic at least now its not giving me errors anymore <3 ill post the code when i fix it.

Comment: sorry, my bad . didntpay attention to that in hurry

Comment: @JoshuaRockyLizardi  changing `while(i>0&&j>0)` to `while(i>0||j>0)` should solve the problem

Comment: this edit works perfectly `System.out.println("path taken");
int curr=F[rowLen - 1][columnLen - 1];
int i=rowLen-1;
int j=columnLen-1;
paste(i+1,j+1);
 while(i>0||j>0){
    if(i>0&&F[i-1][j]==curr){
        i=i-1;
        paste(i+1,j+1);
    }
    else if(j>0&&F[i][j-1]==curr){
        j=j-1;
        paste(i+1,j+1);
    }
    else if(i>0&&F[i-1][j]==curr-1){    
        i=i-1;
        curr--;
        paste(i+1,j+1);
    }
    else if(j>0&&F[i][j-1]==curr-1){    
        j=j-1;
        curr--;
        paste(i+1,j+1);  
    }

}paste(i,j);`

Comment: hmm in your example you wantedto print (3,3) after (4,4). So thats why i skipped printing those steps

Comment: whoops! that was a typo!! should be a 3,4 between  sry, its ok though i learned so much from having to edit the code, thank you so much for your time and help!